# ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryMethodEvaluationContextProvider

Tags: spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc

Following the [Getting Started with R2DBC video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qwF6v6FN_Uc), I convert some of the repositories to reactive in an existing Spring Boot application with PostgreSQL as the database. The application works before the conversion. After I try to start up the application, I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'albumReactResource' defined in file [/app/classes/com/mycompany/myapp/web/rest/react/AlbumReactResource.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'albumReactRepository' defined in class path resource [com/mycompany/myapp/config/ReactDatabaseConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'albumReactRepository' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'r2dbcRepositoryFactory' defined in class path resource [com/mycompany/myapp/config/ReactDatabaseConfig.class]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.data.r2dbc.repository.support.R2dbcRepositoryFactory] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@4e0e2f2a]
...
gallery-app_1         | Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryMethodEvaluationContextProvider
gallery-app_1         |  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
gallery-app_1         |  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
gallery-app_1         |  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
gallery-app_1         |  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
gallery-app_1         |  ... 51 common frames omitted
```

The QueryMethodEvaluationContextProvider class should be there. I guess that the database configuration can't co-exist with the existing database and Spring Data configuration.

The Spring Boot version is 2.0.5.RELEASE. And related dependencies are the followings:

```
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux"
compile "org.springframework.data:spring-data-jdbc:1.0.0.r2dbc-SNAPSHOT"
compile "io.r2dbc:r2dbc-postgresql:1.0.0.M5"
```

Here is the database configuration which is the same as the code for the video:

Configuration
public class ReactDatabaseConfig {

```
@Bean
PostgresqlConnectionFactory connectionFactory(){
    return new PostgresqlConnectionFactory(

            PostgresqlConnectionConfiguration.builder()
                .host("localhost")
                .database("gallery")
                .username("postgres")
                .password("")
                .build()
        );
    }

    @Bean
    DatabaseClient databaseClient(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory){

        return DatabaseClient.builder()
                .connectionFactory(connectionFactory)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    R2dbcRepositoryFactory r2dbcRepositoryFactory(DatabaseClient client){

        RelationalMappingContext context = new RelationalMappingContext();
        context.afterPropertiesSet();

        return new R2dbcRepositoryFactory(client, context);
    }

    @Bean
    AlbumReactRepository albumReactRepository(R2dbcRepositoryFactory factory){
        return factory.getRepository(AlbumReactRepository.class); <-- exceptions occurs
    }
 ...
}
```

Some related dependency information as the followings:

```
+--- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jdbc:1.0.0.r2dbc-SNAPSHOT
|    +--- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:2.1.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT -> 2.0.10.RELEASE (*)
...
+--- org.springframework.security:spring-security-data -> 5.0.8.RELEASE
|    +--- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.0
|    +--- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:2.0.10.RELEASE (*)
...
|    +--- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:2.0.10.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:2.0.10.RELEASE
```

How to fix this problem?

Comment: You need to provide more information. Especially: What versions do you use?

Comment: @JensSchauder Thanks. I have updated my question with version information.

Comment: Please run `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose` it should show that you have multiple dependencies of Spring Data Commons. Explicitly add the later version as a dependency.

Comment: @JensSchauder I post a portion of the dependency tree. Do you mean that I need to exclude the version 2.0.10 and use 2.1.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT instead?

Comment: Yes. While I don't exactly understand right now why this triggered this specific exception, Spring Data JDBC and thereby Spring Data R2DBC won't work with Spring Data Commons 2.0. Probably the best way to get consistent versions is to use Spring Boot 2.1.M4

Answer (score -1):

Make sure `AlbumReactRepository` is extending 
`org.springframework.data.repository.reactive.ReactiveCrudRepository`

and not

```
org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository
```

Comment: That is what I did.